# Pandas: calculate average number of rows per user per day

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Pandas DataFrame` which has a `DATE` column and a `userid` column like so:

```
    userid      DATE
0   vDKE27PF6z  2016-05-26
1   z6XJewg04Y  2016-05-25
2   e5Fsyak59l  2016-05-25
3   7SaYpGRtMI  2016-05-25
4   KGmTH0XOMz  2016-05-25
```

There are many distinct `DATE` values and for each `DATE` a particular `userid` can appear twice. For each date, I'd like to calculate the number of rows that correspond to that `DATE` divided by the  number of unique `userid` values that appear for a given `DATE`. What's the best way to do this? I've tried various permutations of `groupby`, but these don't go where I want to be.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"userid": ["vDKE27PF6z",  "vDKE27PF6z", "e5Fsyak59l", "7SaYpGRtMI", "KGmTH0XOMz"  ], "DATE" : ["2016-05-25","2016-05-25","2016-05-25","2016-05-25","2016-05-26"]})

dates = df.groupby("DATE").count() # Number of occurrences of each date
dates["uniques"] = df.groupby("DATE").userid.nunique() # Number of unique users per day
dates["ratio"] = dates.userid/dates.uniques # Ratio of the two
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby('DATE')['userid'].agg(lambda x:x.nunique()*1.0/x.count())
```

in python3 would be fine without the `*1.0`

Answer (score 0):

`pd.groupby` is the way to go. I think you're looking for the `describe()` function. It gives simple statistics about the DataFrame in question.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'userid':['vDKE27PF6z', 'z6XJewg04Y', 
                               'e5Fsyak59l', '7SaYpGRtMI', 'KGmTH0XOMz'],
                     'DATE': ['2016-05-26', '2016-05-25', 
                              '2016-05-25', '2016-05-25', '2016-05-25']})

for ind, grp in data.groupby('DATE'):
    print(grp.describe())
```

The output is a pd.DataFrame object that has a `count` of the number of objects in that group, and the number of `unique` objects in that group. Sample output below:

```
>>>              DATE      userid
   count            4           4
   unique           1           4
   top     2016-05-25  7SaYpGRtMI
   freq             4           1

>>>              DATE      userid
   count            1           1
   unique           1           1
   top     2016-05-26  vDKE27PF6z
   freq             1           1
```

Notice for date '2016-05-25', there is one unique date (of course) and 4 unique user ids. More information about the `describe()` function can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have

```
df
    userid  DATE
0   vDKE27PF6z  2016-05-26
1   z6XJewg04Y  2016-05-25
2   e5Fsyak59l  2016-05-25
3   7SaYpGRtMI  2016-05-25
4   KGmTH0XOMz  2016-05-25
```

Then you may proceed as follows:

```
df.groupby('DATE',as_index=False).agg(lambda x: 1/len(np.unique(x)))
          DATE  userid
0   2016-05-25  0.25
1   2016-05-26  1.00
```